# Масштабирование изображения fancyBox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Возможно ли выводить изображение с большим разрешением полностью (без скролов) в popup окне, используя fancyBox?

**JavaScript**

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe"
});
```

Спасибо

Comment: а если изображение 3800х2500 а размер "форточки" 1376х768 ? как быть с этим ? или скорость интернет не 100мгб/сек а как быть в этом случае ?

Comment: `iframe : {
        scrolling : 'no'
    }` ?  ....... в доки идем http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs  там написано ......не?

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за ответ. Это не совсем то, что пытаюсь сделать. В данном случае просто удаляются скролы окна, но масштаб изображения остается таким же. Скорее всего проще будет изменять картинку до того, как выводить в окне